# Validation is working, but alert/message is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I realized Safari isn't compatible with the HTML5 required feature, so I tried to add in a Javascript validation script. The script is blocking the customer from moving forward, but the alert OR message is not showing up.

```
<div class="productdetailquantity"><?php echo"<form action='./itemsadded.php?view_product=$product_id' method='POST' id='formID'>"?>
<select class="productsize" id="sizeoption" name='size' required><span id="sizeoptionMSG" style="margin-left:6px;color:darkred;"></span>
    <option value=''>Select a Size</option>
    <option value='Small'>Small</option>
    <option value='Medium'>Medium</option>
    <option value='Large'>Large</option>
    <option value='XL'>XL</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <select class="productquantity" name='quantity'>
     <option value='1'>1</option>
     <option value='2'>2</option>
     <option value='3'>3</option>
     <option value='4'>4</option>
 </select>
</div><br><br>
<div class="productdetailaddbutton">


  <?php 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id' />
        <input type='submit' class='addtocart' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to cart' />";
    ?>


<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: 

<form id="formID">
form.noValidate = true;
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // listen for form submitting
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
            document.getElementById('sizeoptionMSG').innerHTML = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'Please, select a size' : ''; // Show message, NOT SHOWING UP
            document.getElementById('sizeoption').style.borderColor = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'darkred' : ''; // color field's border -- NOT SHOWING UP
            if (document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') document.getElementById('sizeoption').focus(); // Put cursor back to the field -- NOT WORKING
            alert('Please, select a size.'); // error message -- NOT WORKING
        }
    }, false);
```

Does anyone see anything that would be causing this to not display the alert or message? I've commented in the JS on those parts which are not working. Again, the validation works, but the message or alert is not displaying.

UPDATE:

I receive this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

For this line:

document.getElementById('sizeoptionMSG').innerHTML = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'Please, select a size' : ''; // Show message

UPDATE to show current JS code:

```
    <script>
    var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: <form id="formID">
        form.noValidate = true;
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // listen for form submitting
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
        document.getElementById('sizeoptionMSG').innerHTML = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? '*Please, select a size' : ''; // Show message
        if(document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('sizeoption').className += 'invalid-input';
    } // color field's border
        if (document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') document.getElementById('sizeoption').focus(); // Put cursor back to the field
        alert('Please, select a size.'); // error message
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

CSS for invalid-input:

```
.invalid-input {
border-color: #990000;
}
```

Comment: lookslike `event.target.checkValidity()` is always returning `true` or else the statements above `alert` are breaking into `errors`. check the console once

Comment: If nothing inside that if works, how are you so sure the validation itself works? Have you validated this in another way and have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: It does not allow the page to move forward if an option is not selected.

Comment: I updated my question and added the console error.

Comment: well because you mis-placed `span` with id `sizeoptionMSG` in `select` tag before option

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question because your html is invalid:

Here is me trying my best to change it to look ok:

```
<form action="itemsadded.php" method="post" id="formID">
  <div class="product-detail-quantity">
      <span id="sizeoptionMSG"></span>
      <select class="product-size" id="sizeoption" name="size" required>
          <option value="">Select a Size</option>
          <option value="Small">Small</option>
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="Large">Large</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
       </select>
      <select class="product-quantity" name="quantity">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="product-detail-addbutton">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?=$product_id;?>">
      <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart" name="add_to_cart">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: 

    form.noValidate = true;
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // listen for form submitting
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
            document.getElementById('sizeoptionMSG').innerHTML = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'Please, select a size' : ''; // Show message, NOT SHOWING UP
            document.getElementById('sizeoption').style.borderColor = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'darkred' : ''; // color field's border -- NOT SHOWING UP
            if (document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') document.getElementById('sizeoption').focus(); // Put cursor back to the field -- NOT WORKING
            alert('Please, select a size.'); // error message -- NOT WORKING
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

You had tags that were wrongly opened and closed. Also, you are not allowed to have `span` inside `select`.

EDIT: I just realized that you didn't have consistency in double or single quotes. I just changed the code above with consistent double quotes. I, personally love double quotes, so, I always keep everything in double quotes. Also, never wrap HTML inside a PHP echo. Use PHP echo or `<?=$var;?>` only for the needed parts (just like I did it).

EDIT: Also forgot to mention. Do not use `<br>` to arrange layout elements. `<br>` should only be used with text. If you need margins between the selects, just add something like `.productdetailquantity select { margin: 5px 0; }` in your CSS. This is just an example. Also, for having readable CSS classes, separate each word using dash/hyphen or underscore. E.g `productsize` becomes `product-size`

EDIT: Also, never do "./itemsadded.php?view_product=$product_id" with forms if you are trying to insert an item to db or whatever. You are already sending `$product_id` through a field, so "itemsadded.php" is just enough. You also don't need the "./" because it is already checking the path relative to current path.

EDIT: For the following line:

```
document.getElementById('sizeoption').style.borderColor = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'darkred' : ''; // color field's border -- NOT SHOWING UP
```

don't do that. You set the styles for things like that in class and just add class through JS:

```
if(document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('sizeoption').className += ' invalid-input';
}
```

Also, I think in overall scenario, jQuery will fit your needs better. With jquery, the code above will look like:

```
 $('#formId').submit(function(e) {
     if(e.target.checkValidity()) {
         e.preventDefault();
         if($('#sizeoption').val() == '')) {
             $('#sizeoption').addClass('invalid-input');
         }
         // ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have to have  "./itemsadded.php?view_product=$product_id"  because it is pulling data from a link from before. If I do it just like itemsadded.php the next page will not locate it. I appreciate all of the effort you put into this question. The errror message and line message is working now, but I can't seem to get the cursor to go back to that field or for the input box to change colors. I am updating my question to show what I have for the JS. I tried the Jquery code you posted, but it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Yes but you already have the product_id as a POST parameter. So, in PHP you can just do something like: `$product_id = $_POST['product_id']; validate($product_id); header("Location: /viewProduct.php?product_id={$product_id}");` Just a thought :) what do you mean by "cursor going back to field"? Are you talking about focus?

Comment: Here is a codepen that does what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXopyp. It uses jQuery. I think the reason this jquery didn't work is because you didn't put it inside `$(document).ready`. Also, instead of checking the value of `sizeoption` three times, you can just test it once and add everything inside the `if` block. Just like how I did it.

Comment: I tried this Jquery and it still doesn't do anything. Even in your codepen, it just makes the html5 required 'This field must be filled in' box appear. I still have no idea why the invalid input class isn't working.